# Shiny.i18n not translate the modal dialoge rendered within module

Tags: r, json, shiny, internationalization, translation

I want to translate parts of my UI in a modularized shiny app. As I summarized my simplified code,
in the first module I have no problem with i18n as it is enters to the module 1 with argument i18n and
translation works well in registerUI(based on recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756339/translate-shiny-app-using-shiny-i18n-in-modules)). But my problem is with the UI of module 2 (M2UI) which this function
itself called within the server of module 1 (register) to return a modal dialogue. But i18n not detected and translation not works on displayed new modal. Any suggestions why this happens? thanks in advance...

I edited my example and it is now completely reproducible. Translation csv files are available [here](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.i18n/tree/master/examples/data). Just copy them in "translations" forlder. And, the modules should be copied to "modules" folder.

```
## CSV translation files are available at : https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.i18n/tree/master/examples/data

# Copy "translation_it.csv" and "translation_pl.csv" files to "translations" folder

###### make modules and copy them into folder "modules"
source("modules/register.R")
source("modules/M2.R")
#####

library(shiny)
library(shiny.i18n)
library(shinydashboard)
 
i18n <- Translator$new(translation_csvs_path = "translations")
i18n$set_translation_language("en")
shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n) 

############################ UI

header <- dashboardHeader(title = i18n$t('Hello Shiny!'), titleWidth = 400 ,
                          
                          tags$li( fluidRow( 
                            shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n),
                            div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; font-size: 10px; height=30px;width: 150px;",selectInput(
                              inputId='selected_language',
                              label=i18n$t('Change language'),
                              choices = i18n$get_languages(),
                              selected = i18n$get_key_translation()
                            )) 
                            
                         
                             
                          ),
                          class = "dropdown") 
                           
                          
                          
)


# Sidebar Menu ------------------------------------------------------------
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 220,
                            
                            sidebarMenu(
                              menuItem( i18n$t("Hello Shiny!"), tabName = "diary", icon = icon("align-justify")),
                              menuItem("Help", tabName = "help", icon = icon("table")),
                              #menuItem("Data analysis", tabName = "descriptive", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
                              menuItem("About", tabName = "about", icon = icon("info-circle"))
                              
                            ) 
                            
) 



body <- dashboardBody(
  
  
  tabItems(
    tabItem("diary", 
            # includeMarkdown("Introduction.Rmd"),
            # includeMarkdown("Contact.Rmd")
            titlePanel(i18n$t("Hello Shiny!")),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput("bins",
                            i18n$t("Number of bins:"),
                            min = 1,
                            max = 50,
                            value = 30)
              ),
              mainPanel(
                plotOutput("distPlot"),
                actionButton("test","test"),
                p(i18n$t("This is description of the plot."))
              )
            ),
            tags$style(type = "text/css", ".recalculating {opacity: 1.0;}"),   # Prevents gray screen during Sys.sleep()
            
    ), 
    
    
    
    tabItem("help", 
            
    ), 
    
    tabItem("about",
            
    )
  )
  
)




ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'Coronavirus', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')


#################################### SERVER


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  
  
  observeEvent(input$selected_language, {
    update_lang(session, input$selected_language)
  })
  
  shiny::observeEvent(input$test, {
    
       registerUI(id = "REG",reg_title=i18n$t("Hello Shiny!"),i18n=i18n )  #This ID should be mached with ID in server
      
    
  })
  
   callModule(register,id = "REG", title= i18n$t("Hello Shiny!"), i18n=i18n )
   
  
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins,
         col = "darkgray", border = "white",
         main = i18n$t("Histogram of x"), ylab = i18n$t("Frequency"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

registerUI <- function(id, reg_title=NULL  ,i18n) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)

  shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n)  
  
  showModal(tags$div( modalDialog(title = "" ,size="s",
                                             
                                             shiny::div(id =ns("regpanel"),   
                                                        shiny::wellPanel(
                                                          shiny::tags$h2(reg_title, class = "text-center", style = "padding-top: 0;"),
                                                          
                                                          shinyjs::disabled(shiny::textInput(ns("user_name1"), value= "", shiny::tagList(shiny::icon("user"), "suggested user name"))) ,# 
                                                              shiny::actionButton(ns("regSubmit"),  i18n$t("Submit") , class = "btn-primary", style = "color: white;")
                                                            
                                                          ) 
                                                          
                                                          
                                                        )
                                             ),
                                             
                                             
                                             easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL )) 
}


###### Module 1

register <- function(input, output, session ,title,i18n) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
   shiny::observeEvent(input$regSubmit, {
     shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n)     
     removeModal() 
     M2UI(id =   ns("M2") ,reg_title=i18n$t("Hello Shiny!" ),i18n=i18n ) 
     
     
  })
   callModule(M2,id = "M2" , title= i18n$t("Hello Shiny!"),i18n=i18n)

}

###### Module 2
M2UI <- function(id, reg_title=NULL,i18n ) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n) 
  
    showModal(modalDialog(title = reg_title ,size="s",
                          
                        shiny::wellPanel(
                          
                          shiny::actionButton(ns("Finish"),  i18n$t("Hello Shiny!" ) )
                          
                        ) 
                        
                        , easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL ) )
 
}


M2 <- function(input, output, session ,title,i18n) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  shiny::observeEvent(input$Finish, {
    
    removeModal()
    
  })
  
  
}
```

Comment: Try `registerUI(id = ns("REG"), i18n=i18n )`

Comment: Hello YBS, your recommendation not works. I tried to more simplify the situation for myself. for clarification suppose a button which after click on it a module returns a modal dialogue, in this modal translation is OK. But if just after Module_UI() line in observeEvent() you calls Module_server with callModule() which can remove previous modal and open a new one, now in this new modal translation not works!. Thus I think the problem is related to callModule() function. But I not found any solution yet.

Comment: I am surprised it works at all. There are at least two syntax errors in the code: 1) missing closing bracket for `sidebar` before `body`. 2) missing comma in `showModal` in `registerUI` module 2. - I am not sure I can help but my next try would be to check the reactive domain (`i18n$t` uses per default `shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain()`).

Comment: Unfortunately my above code is not reproducable. I will edit it and replace a reproducible code to clarify the problem.

Comment: Now I edited the example code and it is now reproducible. The problem is that i18n not translate the texts in modal dialogue 2.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the latest dev version? You have to update it through the dev package. I am pretty sure it was fixed there. The problem regarded a missing callback through shiny session.

Your exampe works on my setup.

Comment: Dear Hamidburg, thanks for your answer. Are you sure it works in second modal dialogue after clicking on submit button in first modal? I installed dev version of shiny.i18n but the problem is not resolved!. Translation is not done  for second modal dialogue!  Please if it is possible for you check it again and let me know. Thanks