# How do I reuse a user element in R shiny?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I am writing a shiny app where I have a sidebarPanel containing various interactive user elements. This sidebarPanel is embedded in the ui in such a way:

**Server/UI**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title="some title",
  tabPanel(
    title="Tab 1",
    sidebarLayout(
      # This is the element I want to reuse, see second tabPanel
      sidebarPanel(radioButtons(inputId="button1", label="Choose", choices=c("1", "2"))),
      mainPanel(uiOutput("output1"))
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title="Tab 2",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(radioButtons(inputId="button1", label="Choose", choices=c("1", "2"))),
      mainPanel(uiOutput("output2"))
    )
  )
)
  
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$output1 <- renderText("Text 1")
  output$output2 <- renderText("Text 2")
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I have tried creating a module such as they did in [Translate shiny app using shiny.i18n in modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756339/translate-shiny-app-using-shiny-i18n-in-modules)

**Module module.R**

```
library(shiny)

samplePanel <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons(inputId="button1", label="Choose", choices=c("1", "2")),
    textOutput("sample_text")
  )
}

sampleModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$sample_text <- renderText("Sample text")
}
```

**New Server/UI main script**

```
source("module.R")

library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title="some title",
  tabPanel(
    title="Tab 1",
    sidebarLayout(
      samplePanel("moduleId"),
      mainPanel(uiOutput("output1"))
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title="Tab 2",
    sidebarLayout(
      samplePanel("moduleId"),
      mainPanel(uiOutput("output2"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(sampleModule, "moduleId")
  output$output1 <- renderText("Text 1")
  output$output2 <- renderText("Text 2")
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

What is it I don't understand about modularizing shiny code? One thing that surprises me is that my `samplePanel` doesn't even show the `sample_text` I want it to show.

Edit: Fixed the trivial error regarding text rendering in the sidebarPanel.

Comment: Here's a recent blog post on this exact topic with a step-by-step:  https://dataenthusiast.ca/2023/how-to-modularize-existing-shiny-app/

Comment: Thanks @PaulStaffordAllen, I will look into it and update this question once I have further questions or resolved my issue!

Comment: You need to give the two instances of your module different IDs and wrap your `inputId`s in `ns()` inside your module UI.

Comment: ... And use something like `output$sample_text <- renderText("Sample text")` in your module server.

Comment: @Limey Oops, that makes sense. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Limey However, regarding the two different ids - wouldn't that create two different ui elements with the exact same appearance, but different behaviour? I.e., if I select radio button two in tab 1, and then switch to tab 2, tab 2 would still show radio button one to be selected, right?

Comment: Yes, it would.  I thought that's what you wanted.  If it isn't, please clarify.

Comment: Where did you find the code for writing Shiny modules? If you consult the [official documentation](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/) or [the book](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html) you’ll see that the function you are using is deprecated, and that you should be using `moduleServer()`, which vastly simplifies using modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you something close to what you want?

```
library(shiny)

samplePanel <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons(inputId=ns("button1"), label="Choose", choices=c("1", "2")),
    textOutput(ns("sample_text"))
  )
}

sampleModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$sample_text <- renderText("Sample text")
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  title="some title",
  tabPanel(
    title="Tab 1",
    sidebarLayout(
      samplePanel("moduleId1"),
      mainPanel(uiOutput("output1"))
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title="Tab 2",
    sidebarLayout(
      samplePanel("moduleId2"),
      mainPanel(uiOutput("output2"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(sampleModule, "moduleId1")
  callModule(sampleModule, "moduleId2")
  output$output1 <- renderText("Text 1")
  output$output2 <- renderText("Text 2")
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

**EDIT**

In response to discussion in comments, this layout moves the module from the `tabPanel` sidebar to the page sidebar, meaning that a single instance is common to each of the `tabPanel`s.  As there's now only a single instance, there may not be any need to use a module.

```
library(shiny)

samplePanel <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons(inputId=ns("button1"), label="Choose", choices=c("1", "2")),
    textOutput(ns("sample_text"))
  )
}

sampleModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$sample_text <- renderText("Sample text")
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  title="some title",
    samplePanel("moduleId1"),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        title="Tab 1",
        uiOutput("output1")
      ),
      tabPanel(
        title="Tab 2",
        uiOutput("output2")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(sampleModule, "moduleId1")
  output$output1 <- renderText("Text 1")
  output$output2 <- renderText("Text 2")
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Please *accept* this answer if it is useful, rather than merely *upvoting* it.  Click the tick mark close to the up- and downvote buttons.  Thank you.

Comment: I'd like the sidebarPanel to stay constant across tabs. I.e., user element selections should not change when the tab is changed. So I am guessing I need to somehow include the same element in various places, but I'm not sure how that would be done in the context of shiny.

Comment: Ah.  Ok.  That can't be done.  (As far as I know.)  What you can do is put different instances of the same module on different tabs and have them communicate with each other so that they stay consistent. `session$userData` is an obvious way to do that.  It might be simpler to remove the module from the `tabPanel`.  That way you have only one instance and consistency isn't an issue.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I'll accept your answer and close this thread then. Thanks for the amazingly quick help and for the pointer towards session$userData! I was not aware of that data structure.

Comment: Please don’t recommend the outdated/deprecated API for creating modules. It’s time to let it die.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What are you referring to? Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Fair point.  I was addressing OPs main question.  I am in the process of providing a link to the current API.

Comment: See [this page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) for more information about Shiny modules.

Comment: @J.Grünenwald See the comment directly below your question.

Comment: @Limey I have adopted your suggested solution and while it does work, I am not sure whether this looks the way I'd like it to. I did like the tabs showing up at the top of the app next to the title. I take it the only way to achieve that is by doing what you suggested earlier and having the instances of ```samplePanel``` communicate with each other via ```session$userData```?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what you will need to do.  The tricky bit will be avoiding infinite recursion as a change in one module triggers a change in the second which triggers a chnage in the first, and so on. `isolate` will be your friend.  And I susepect you will need to use some sort of proxy flag in `session$userData` or in an additional argument to the module server function.  Only you can decide whether the different/improved aesthetics justify the additional effort.

Comment: ... and @KonradRudolf's comment about the API is correct.  The only reason I didn't mention it in my answer is that I felt it would have distracted from your original question.  They beat me to the punch in comments. :-)